# ¿Cómo puedo llamar al if después de completar los valores en los inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

Quiero que el programa me calcule el costo que tienes por cada mes pero este cambia según la temporada y la formula para sacar el costo cambia según los parámetros como el la primera si es menor de 76 se realiza una ecuación pero si es mayor de 76 se realiza otra diferente entonces quiero que después de poner el valor de los inputs se ejecuten el if ya que con el resultado sabremos si es la primera o la segunda condición y esto lo tengo que hacer con cada mes pero para hacerlo primero necesito sacar en el primero, ya había publicado la pregunta pero me comentaron que lo simplificará. Esto es lo más simple a mi parecer:

```js
 //invierno 
  var mes31 = 31;
  var mes30 = 30;
  var mes28 = 28;
  var invierno1 = 0.793;
  var invierno2 = 0.956;
  var invierno3 = 2.802;
  // verano 
  
  var verano1 = 0.569;
  var verano2 = 0.718;
  var verano3 = 1.727;
  var verano4 = 2.745;
 
 

 



function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
  var result11 = document.getElementById("result11");
  var result12 = document.getElementById("result12");
  // verano 
  var result5 = document.getElementById("result5");
  var result6 = document.getElementById("result6");
  var result7 = document.getElementById("result7");
  var result8 = document.getElementById("result8");
  var result9 = document.getElementById("result9");
  var result10 = document.getElementById("result10");
  
//invierno 
  result1.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));
  result2.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes28));
  result3.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes30));
  result4.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes30));
  result11.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes30));
  result12.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));

  // verano 
  result5.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));
  result6.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes30));
  result7.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));
  result8.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));
  result9.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes30));
  result10.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mes31));
  
  
  
  if(result1 < 76){
  function enerores1 () {
    var inv1 = ((invierno1  * result1)* 1.16);
    Document.getElementById("result1.1").innerHTML = inv1;
  }
  enerores1();
}
else{
 var inv2 =  ((invierno1*75+(E2-75)*invierno2)*1.16);
  Document.getElementById("result1.1").innerHTML = inv2;
}
}
```

```html
<form oninput="calc()">
      <input id="a" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="c" type="number" value="0"><br>
      <h1>invierno</h1>
      <output id="result1"></output><output id="result1.1"></output><br>
      <output id="result2"></output><br>
      <output id="result3"></output><br>
      <output id="result4"></output><br>
      <output id="result11"></output><br>
      <output id="result12"></output><br>
      <h1>verano</h1>
      <output id="result5"></output><br>
      <output id="result6"></output><br>
      <output id="result7"></output><br>
      <output id="result8"></output><br>
      <output id="result9"></output><br>
      <output id="result10"></output><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu función se ejecute cada vez que se modifica el valor en los input, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input id="a" type="number" value="0" oninput="calc()">
<input id="b" type="number" value="0" oninput="calc()">
<input id="c" type="number" value="0" oninput="calc()"><br>
```

De esta forma, cada que se modifique un valor podrás entrar a la función calc() en dónde realizas todos tus cálculos.

Ahora, en la parte del if, eliminaría la función y simplemente lo pondría dentro de los corchetes.

```
if(result1 < 76){
  var inv1 = ((invierno1  * result1)* 1.16);
  Document.getElementById("result1.1").innerHTML = inv1;
}
else{
  var inv2 =  ((invierno1*75+(E2-75)*invierno2)*1.16);
  Document.getElementById("result1.1").innerHTML = inv2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchos eventos, pon a escuchar con un onchange, asi cada que se ponga un valor en el input podras ejecutar una funcion...>

```
$(input[name="inputValor1"]).on("change", ()=>{
alert("Llego a este input" + $(input[name="inputValor1"]).val();
})
```

Comment: y como pudiera hacer que las condiciones aparecieran por que ya hice algunos cambios y aun no logro que me salga el resultado en el output

Comment: Si estas poniendo bien el .Val()  ?

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que quiera insertar el resultado en algun lugar, eneste caso un output, puedes hacer uso de Jquery.

Cuando operas un dato lo puedes almacenar en una variable...
    Var c = a+b

Ahora que ya tienes el resultado puedes meterlos pero primero debes ubicar donde,ahora los outputs nunca los he usado, siempre meto los resultados en otros inputs o en campos de texto con estilos asi que asumiré que tienes un input con una clase Result.

Ahora seleccionas el input y le metes la variable asi.

```
$('.Result').val(c)
```

Siendo c la variable que contiene el resultado, ahora no olvides que Val se usa en este caso con inputs asi que puede que si haces lo mismo con otra etiqueta pueda que no funcione, sin embargo, funcionará si usas un input, intenta val con la etiqueta output a ver como te va.